# strange packets seen when using okhttp to upload a file

Tags: java, okhttp

I am trying to upload a file into a server through okhttp, I am using a form so using the MultipartBuilder.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType OCTET_STREAM = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBuilder()
            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition",
                                "form-data; name=\"breadcrumb\"; filename=\"myfile.bin\"",
                                "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary"),
                     RequestBody.create(OCTET_STREAM, file))
            .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", cred)
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

But when tracing what goes on the wire:

```
POST /breadcrumb/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic aHl6OmhvbGExMjM=
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=9bc835d6-24b8-42c4-ae8d-5bc89b3fe68f
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: myurl:8000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

10e
--9bc835d6-24b8-42c4-ae8d-5bc89b3fe68f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="breadcrumb"; filename="myfile.bin"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 21

some file content in binary

--9bc835d6-24b8-42c4-ae8d-5bc89b3fe68f--
0
```

When I use the traditional Apache http builders, it looks similar, but I don't see the strange characters at the beginning and at the end (10e, 0). Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's the chunked transfer encoding doing its job (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified exact Content-Length header, so OkHttpClient started to use chunked transfer encoding.

In HTTP protocol receiver must always know exact length of content(for purpose of allocating memory or other resources) before content will be realy send to server. There is two ways to send it - whole length of content in Content-Length header or by using chucked encoding if content-length can't be calculated at start of request.

This line:

```
10e
```

is just says that after that line client will send part of some data with length 0x10e (270) bytes.

Comment: I am using okhttp 2.0.0, and I believe there was a bug already fixed in this version, are other users of this library seeing the same?

Comment: It's totally not a bug. It must be like that. It standard feature included in HTTP 1.1 standard. It do this because it must. If client don't specify Content-Length, and Chucked transfer encoded will not be used, then there is no way for server to understand how many resources he needs to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

The current `MultipartBuilder` implementation does not support setting a fixed Content-Length. One option would be implementing a `FixedMultipartBuilder`, which does its magic in the `public long contentLength()` method. Instead of returning `-1L` it now computes the length, e.g.:

```java
import com.squareup.okhttp.Headers;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import okio.BufferedSink;
import okio.ByteString;

/**
 * Fluent API to build <a href="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387.txt">RFC
 * 2387</a>-compliant request bodies.
 */
public final class FixedMultipartBuilder {

  private static final byte[] COLONSPACE = { ':', ' ' };
  private static final byte[] CRLF = { '\r', '\n' };
  private static final byte[] DASHDASH = { '-', '-' };

  private final ByteString boundary;
  private MediaType type = MultipartBuilder.MIXED;

  // Parallel lists of nullable headers and non-null bodies.
  private final List<Headers> partHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
  private final List<RequestBody> partBodies = new ArrayList<>();

  /** Creates a new multipart builder that uses a random boundary token. */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder() {
    this(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new multipart builder that uses {@code boundary} to separate
   * parts. Prefer the no-argument constructor to defend against injection
   * attacks.
   */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder(String boundary) {
    this.boundary = ByteString.encodeUtf8(boundary);
  }

  /**
   * Set the MIME type. Expected values for {@code type} are
   * {@link com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder#MIXED} (the default),
   * {@link com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder#ALTERNATIVE},
   * {@link com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder#DIGEST},
   * {@link com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder#PARALLEL} and
   * {@link com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder#FORM}.
   */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder type(MediaType type) {
    if (type == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("type == null");
    }
    if (!type.type().equals("multipart")) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("multipart != " + type);
    }
    this.type = type;
    return this;
  }

  /** Add a part to the body. */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder addPart(RequestBody body) {
    return addPart(null, body);
  }

  /** Add a part to the body. */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder addPart(Headers headers, RequestBody body) {
    if (body == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("body == null");
    }
    if (headers != null && headers.get("Content-Type") != null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected header: Content-Type");
    }
    if (headers != null && headers.get("Content-Length") != null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected header: Content-Length");
    }

    partHeaders.add(headers);
    partBodies.add(body);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Appends a quoted-string to a StringBuilder.
   *
   * <p>RFC 2388 is rather vague about how one should escape special characters
   * in form-data parameters, and as it turns out Firefox and Chrome actually
   * do rather different things, and both say in their comments that they're
   * not really sure what the right approach is. We go with Chrome's behavior
   * (which also experimentally seems to match what IE does), but if you
   * actually want to have a good chance of things working, please avoid
   * double-quotes, newlines, percent signs, and the like in your field names.
   */
  private static StringBuilder appendQuotedString(StringBuilder target, String key) {
    target.append('"');
    for (int i = 0, len = key.length(); i < len; i++) {
      char ch = key.charAt(i);
      switch (ch) {
        case '\n':
          target.append("%0A");
          break;
        case '\r':
          target.append("%0D");
          break;
        case '"':
          target.append("%22");
          break;
        default:
          target.append(ch);
          break;
      }
    }
    target.append('"');
    return target;
  }

  /** Add a form data part to the body. */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder addFormDataPart(String name, String value) {
    return addFormDataPart(name, null, RequestBody.create(null, value));
  }

  /** Add a form data part to the body. */
  public FixedMultipartBuilder addFormDataPart(String name, String filename, RequestBody value) {
    if (name == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("name == null");
    }
    StringBuilder disposition = new StringBuilder("form-data; name=");
    appendQuotedString(disposition, name);

    if (filename != null) {
      disposition.append("; filename=");
      appendQuotedString(disposition, filename);
    }

    return addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", disposition.toString()), value);
  }

  /** Assemble the specified parts into a request body. */
  public RequestBody build() {
    if (partHeaders.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Multipart body must have at least one part.");
    }
    return new MultipartRequestBody(type, boundary, partHeaders, partBodies);
  }

  private static final class MultipartRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    private final ByteString boundary;
    private final MediaType contentType;
    private final List<Headers> partHeaders;
    private final List<RequestBody> partBodies;

    public MultipartRequestBody(MediaType type, ByteString boundary, List<Headers> partHeaders,
        List<RequestBody> partBodies) {
      if (type == null) throw new NullPointerException("type == null");

      this.boundary = boundary;
      this.contentType = MediaType.parse(type + "; boundary=" + boundary.utf8());
      this.partHeaders = Util.immutableList(partHeaders);
      this.partBodies = Util.immutableList(partBodies);
    }

    @Override public MediaType contentType() {
      return contentType;
    }

    private long contentLengthForPart(Headers headers, RequestBody body) throws IOException {
      // Check if the body has an contentLength != -1, otherwise cancel!
      long bodyContentLength = body.contentLength();
      if(bodyContentLength < 0L) {
        return -1L;
      }

      long length = 0;

      length += DASHDASH.length + boundary.size() + CRLF.length;

      if (headers != null) {
        for (int h = 0, headerCount = headers.size(); h < headerCount; h++) {
          length += headers.name(h).getBytes().length
                  + COLONSPACE.length
                  + headers.value(h).getBytes().length
                  + CRLF.length;
        }
      }

      MediaType contentType = body.contentType();
      if (contentType != null) {
        length += "Content-Type: ".getBytes().length
                + contentType.toString().getBytes().length
                + CRLF.length;
      }

      length += CRLF.length;
      length += bodyContentLength;
      length += CRLF.length;

      return length;
    }

    @Override public long contentLength() throws IOException {
      long length = 0;

      for (int p = 0, partCount = partHeaders.size(); p < partCount; p++) {
        long contentPartLength = contentLengthForPart(partHeaders.get(p), partBodies.get(p));

        if(contentPartLength < 0) {
          // Too bad, can't get contentPartLength!
          return -1L;
        }

        length += contentPartLength;
      }

      length += DASHDASH.length + boundary.size() + DASHDASH.length + CRLF.length;

      return length;
    }

    @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
      for (int p = 0, partCount = partHeaders.size(); p < partCount; p++) {
        Headers headers = partHeaders.get(p);
        RequestBody body = partBodies.get(p);

        sink.write(DASHDASH);
        sink.write(boundary);
        sink.write(CRLF);

        if (headers != null) {
          for (int h = 0, headerCount = headers.size(); h < headerCount; h++) {
            sink.writeUtf8(headers.name(h))
                .write(COLONSPACE)
                .writeUtf8(headers.value(h))
                .write(CRLF);
          }
        }

        MediaType contentType = body.contentType();
        if (contentType != null) {
          sink.writeUtf8("Content-Type: ")
              .writeUtf8(contentType.toString())
              .write(CRLF);
        }

        // Skipping the Content-Length for individual parts

        sink.write(CRLF);
        partBodies.get(p).writeTo(sink);
        sink.write(CRLF);
      }

      sink.write(DASHDASH);
      sink.write(boundary);
      sink.write(DASHDASH);
      sink.write(CRLF);
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for the long listing... Sadly the `MultipartBuilder` is `final` so we have to copy most of the source instead of simply extend it.